VBA: Using a recursive formula within array
for performance reasons I am assigning a few columns into an array and copying the result back to my sheet. This works well for certain functions, but not for the last one.
In Excel, the function would be =A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0), as I am trying to get the number of the day in a given year.
I am getting a

Run-time error 13:
Type mismatch.

My VBA code looks as follows:
Sub AddYearMonthWeekDay()

Dim i As Long
Dim arr As Variant

    With Worksheets("Source")
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Value2
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 2) = Year(arr(i, 1))
            arr(i, 3) = Month(arr(i, 1))
            arr(i, 4) = Application.WeekNum(arr(i, 1), 2)
            arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 1) - "=DATE(YEAR(" & arr(i, 1) & ",1,0))"
         Next i
            
        .Range("C:E").Insert
        .Range("C1").Value = "Year"
        .Range("D1").Value = "Month"
        .Range("E1").Value = "Week"
        .Range("F1").Value = "Day"
        .Cells(2, "B").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 5) = arr
        .Range("C:F").NumberFormat = "@"
   End With

End Sub

Not sure if the error comes from using wrong quotation.
Trying to use a formula that works well when inserted in a sheet in VBA.
Also using array functionality for speed purpose (many rows).

In this line - arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 1) - "=DATE(YEAR(" & arr(i, 1) & ",1,0))" - you're subtracting a string. You can't evaluate Excel formulas (as text) in VBA like this - use VBA functions instead.

Hi Neil, thanks for the help! I see that now, too. Was trying to substract a formula from the array value, using "= at the start, but forgot to include .Formula in the statement.
By VBA function, do you mean to call a Worksheet.Function or writing a custom function?

arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 1) - CLng(DateSerial(arr(i, 2), 1, 0))

Thanks Ron, unfortunately with that formula I am getting an overflow error.

@HardDisk What line is returning that error? What is the full text of the error? Are you sure you haven't declared something as an Integer somewhere in the code? That would cause a date value to overflow.

You can use the formula of an Excel cell in VBA with the EVALUATE method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate

As of this use:
arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 1) - Application.Evaluate("=DATE(YEAR(" & arr(i, 1) & ",1,0))")
Or use VBA methods:
arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 1) - Dateserial(Year(arr(i, 1)),1,1)

Thanks a lot Black Cat, working perfectly! Will upvote your answer once I am allowed to.

@HardDisk .. anyway you are always allowed to accept an answer by ticking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons, near the top of this answer :-;
